# I want data from datatable and replace comma with space

Tags: mysql

I have query for to get data following :

```
select a from REPLACE(M,',','')TABLE;
```

I want to get all the data from table along with M column content replce , with space.

Comment: [Why should I “tag my RDBMS”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: Replace the comma with space (a blank) or remove it? You have `''`. Do you want `' '` instead?

Comment: What is that query? It doesn't look like it would work. What RDBMS are you using, and what result does that query give?

Comment: I want replace comma with space using mySql @underscore_d

Comment: so [edit] to add the `mqsql` tag, please

Answer (score 1):

You select from the table. What you select belongs in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT t.*, REPLACE(m, ',', '') FROM mytable t;
```

Comment: how i can i write in java